# Overriding Quickbooks Import Function

Tags: xml, import, scripting, quickbooks

I've been tasked with a finding a way to resolve an issue of importing invoices into Quickbooks 2015 professional from a 3rd party system which handles real estate transactions. The problem is Quickbooks imports the invoices from the other system but will not import the invoice number; instead assigning its own invoice number and causing accounting personnel to have to go back into QB and change the invoice number manually (for upwards of 100 invoices a day).

Question is whether there is a way to write a script  which can force QB to import the original invoice number and not override it, or to possibly just write a script to read the invoice fields, put them in a table or csv and then import that into QB?  Any input on how to best tackle this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information here for anyone else to be able to help you. With that said...

The first place to start is with the 3rd party system itself. *If you have access to the source for the 3rd party system*, change it so that it specifies the `RefNumber` value to QuickBooks.

*If you don't, you should talk to the authors of the 3rd party application.* If it communicates with QuickBooks via:

- The QuickBooks Online v2/v3 REST APIs -- you're stuck (unless the 3rd party app devs will change it for you)
- The QuickBooks SDK/COM -- you're stuck (unless the 3rd party app devs will change it for you)
- The Web Connector -- you *might* be able to write a "bridge/relay" of sorts between QuickBooks and the Web Connector to modify the data on the fly
- RDS -- you're stuck (unless the 3rd party app devs will change it for you)

Without knowing what version of QuickBooks you're using, and how your app communicates with it, that's about the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: My apologies. I updated the post. Its Quickbooks 2015 Professional.

Comment: @Alex   For Windows? Or for Mac? Online, or normal desktop app? You also need to tell us how it's currently communicating with QuickBooks...

Comment: Correction: Quickbook Enterprise 2015. Its taking invoices ranging from 1 -30 at a time from an application called TSS which is a title/escrow application which tracks invoices. TSS exports to QB and QB maps to most fields except for state (which QB calls class) and invoice number (which QB is overriding and plugging in its own invoice number which has to be corrected after import). TSS won't state how their system exports to QB except to say the values can be accessed in SQL Server.